# Android Emulator not loading when Google API (API Level 17 or in any other API level) is selected on windows

Tags: performance, android-emulator, google-api, arm, intel-atom

When I choose tagret as Android 4.2.2(API level 17),then emulator takes too long time to load adn starts up.

So I research on it and found solution by using **Intel Atom(x86) instead of ARM(armeabi-v7a) as CPU/ABI and Intel Atom(x86) is really fast ,It helps me by increasing speed of execution.**. 
But I need to run **google service** in my emulator So,I have to switch target **from Android 4.2.2 to Google API**.but when I select Google API then **ARM(armeabi-v7a) is by default is selected and can not able to choose Intel Atom(x86)**..

So I continue with ARM , but here problem is that **emulator is very slow and it doesn't start since last 1 hour**.Any solution ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Google Api's doesn't support Intel HAXM. Try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) and download a VM with gapps e.g.

```
Nexus 7 Jelly Bean with Google Apps
```